# Where on pacer.gov can one order audio files?

Tags: pacer

This PACER training manual mentions audio files but gives no details about them: https://www.pacer.gov/documents/pacermanual.pdf

Can the general pubic order audio files of federal district courtroom testimony on PACER?  If not, what audio files can the public order on PACER?

Comment: I'm curious what's driving this question? Sounds like you're looking for them in bulk, perhaps?

Comment: @mlissner  Yes.  My interest is not in one particular case, but in a type of case (e.g., class action employment discrimination).

Comment: Got it. Well, we can help with some kinds of bulk activities at Free Law Project. If you're interested in chatting, feel free to send me an email: mike@free.law

Answer (score 2):

Not every proceeding will have them, but you can download some of them from the site.

You open the PDF, then look at the attachments.

https://www.cand.uscourts.gov/audio

Comment: The link you provide says, "Effective May 1, 2018, digital audio recordings of select court proceedings can be downloaded from PACER."  What might this mean: "select court proceedings"?

Comment: Whichever proceedings had the audio files added. Not every one got added apparently.

Comment: Is there a system or pattern, or is it just hit and miss?

Comment: I don't work in the federal court house, but I'm sure it just goes by which ones actually put them with the pdf.